Remove and Sort Usings with #if !DEBUG
How I can "save" my "not used" directive using from removing? (Visual Studio 2022)
[screenshot]
I can place using between #if !DEBUG and #endif, but I hope to find something global.
Is there something I can change in the Visual Studio settings?
Thanks.

Edit: More solutions:
Write global using System.Collections.Generic;
Use full qualified within the #if

I faced a similar problem. I couldn't find a fix, but at least for my case the using was a fairly common one (System.Diagnostics) so I "cheated" by adding the using to a global usings file, "GlobalUsings.cs", i.e. I added global using System.Diagnostics; to that file. Now it isn't needed in any code file for that project. I wouldn't want to do that with a rarely-used one, though.

Just use the full qualified within the #if so you don't need the using statement?

Both options are good, but the first option (@Matthew Watson) is good when we have many similar "using" in the project, and the second option (@Ralf) is good when we don't have many similar "using" in the current class :) I think i need to add your workarounds to my workaround

A third option: Only use 'Remove and sort Usings` when you're using 'Debug'  configuration.

This question is similar to: Preprocessor directives and unnecessary Using directives. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@nalka . Yes, it is similar, but I didn't find this post and I don't see a solution there

Hi, you could share your own solution as an answer. @Grazd

I still don't have really good option

Here are examples of how to avoid adding extra using statements:
Example 1: Using Global Usings
// In GlobalUsings.cs
global using System.Diagnostics;

Example 2: Using Fully Qualified Names in #if
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug mode");
#endif

